# Javascript how spawn works for yield

Tags: javascript

I read [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) from Archibald. Great details about Promises, everything is clear, except for the spawn function:

```
function spawn(generatorFunc) {
  function continuer(verb, arg) {
    var result;
    try {
      result = generator[verb](arg);
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    if (result.done) {
      return result.value;
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    }
  }
  var generator = generatorFunc();
  var onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, "next");
  var onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, "throw");
  return onFulfilled();
}
```

I understand the intent, but the above code is not clear. Can someone explain what's going on in the above spawn function, that it magically makes the yield work?

## EDIT 1:

I just read more about generator pattern, and trying to understand how it fits into the above. I'm confused at

- result = generatorverb;
- At the end

  var generator = generatorFunc();
    var onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, "next");
    var onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, "throw");
    return onFulfilled();
  }

## EDIT 2

I think i've figured - its allowing to generator function to yield promises, and then the wrapper spawn function would only execute the "next" on the generator function after the previously returned (yield'ed) promise has resolved. Brain Freeze!

Answer (score 1):

correct if I'm wrong:

1. The first call to onFulfilled() (last line of code in spawn function) would execute continuer function with parameter 'next'.
2. verb value is 'next', so the generator function's 'next' is called via `result = generator[verb](arg);`
3. Now as we see in [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) the generator function returns a promise `let story = yield getJSON('story.json');`
4. The result.value would be set to the Promise (or if all yield are invoked, then done is set to True. Say we are not yet done)
5. Since the done is not yet set, so this piece of code would be executed : `} else { return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);}`
6. That returns a promise, which would ultimately resolve when `getJson(story.json)` is returned. When it resolves, the "then" portion's success handler "onFulfilled" gets called.
7. onFulfilled() : See point 1 : Goes on to do the same thing with upcoming yield